# Generic library dependencies?

Tags: c, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm working on a single file (header + code) communications library in C. It's primarily for my personal use, but there aren't many libraries of this sort available in C, so I'm trying to design it with a mind to releasing it for others to use when it's finished.

In this library, I occasionally have a need for random numbers. For my own projects, I typically use the excellent PCG C library for this. But there are a huge number of random number libraries out there. Directly including or requiring a particular one as part of my library will very likely mean the end user ends up with two such libraries in their codebase.

The options I see:

1. Include a random number library as part of my library (assuming a compatible license).
2. Require the user include a specific library (i.e. PCG) that mine looks to be compiled with.
3. Have my library call a set of generic functions to get random numbers, and require the user to implement those functions, wrapping their random number generator of choice.
4. Register callbacks at init time, and call those callbacks to get a random number from the user.

None of these options seem particularly elegant, as my use of random numbers is an implementation detail and not something the user really needs to be aware of.

Is there any sort of standard or best practice for requiring a non-specific external dependency of this sort?

Answer (score 2):

If flexibility of using different random number libraries is important, I'd go with 4) and register callbacks. You can provide a callback API and let the user implement them or ignore as they see fit.

```
typedef void rand_seed_t (unsigned int);
typedef int  rand_t (void);


...

void mylibrary_init (rand_seed_t* rand_seed_func, 
                     rand_t*      rand_func  
                     /* other stuff */);
```

Now use internal variables to keep track of these two function pointers and call the function pointers whenever you need random numbers.

In this case I picked the same types as `srand` and `rand`, so it would be possible to call the library with those functions if the user doesn't care. Or you could pick them yourself if the user doesn't care and passes on two NULL pointers.

It's very common to have API design where you let the user pass NULL if they don't care to use the more advanced features.